# Class cannot implement TypeScript interface when using static methods

Tags: typescript

TypeScript recognises `static` class methods as valid properties that adhere to an interface when passing the class object as an argument, however it does not like them when the same interface is used to implement the class.

E.g. In the example below, TypeScript accepts that the `Dog` class adheres to the `AnimalMethods` interface when it is passed as an argument inside the `callAnimalMethods` function, however upon attempting to constrain the `Dog` class structure by using `implements AnimalMethods`, the following error is given:

```
Class 'Dog' incorrectly implements interface 'AnimalMethods'.
  Property 'walk' is missing in type 'Dog' but required in type 'AnimalMethods'
```

Example:

```
// error here
class Dog implements AnimalMethods {
  public static walk(): string {
    return 'walk';
  }
}

interface AnimalMethods {
  readonly walk: () => string,
}

function callAnimalMethods(animalObj: AnimalMethods): void {
  animalObj.walk();
}

callAnimalMethods(Dog);
```

Could someone explain why TypeScript does not allow static methods like this to adhere to an interface, especially when the structure is recognised when using the class in an argument.

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMCdIe00AWVwFgBQBjANgQwM56gAiMA5qAJYC2ADluFeAHYAuhAgk9TlgLLgsEMACaEA3ulCgaAVwBGWChlB4WOFktAB3HgGsAFAEoAXCpaQKTchLRSpkATMhNQAch1ZdrgNyTQAX3Q-WQVNVXVNSBkmI1NVCytQGztQBxYnF1coph8-QLR89EsWKAAzHAxwUE5uPgEhUSS-BxxhGCYsAE9tPVMjUABeAD4zBNIAGmbwVvau1Oi+w0GR+MsJ9EK0UuiMDXbQDB4sGqoefkERPH0cLlOsAHk5ACtTE7P6y5NQADcYCmEmrZQDdao8ngA6DwGQy+IEgu5g8HZIywzaHLDHW7vC6ifQkUiGIA).

Comment: When you have `class Foo implements Bar {}` it means an *instance* of `Foo` can be used as a `Bar`.  In your example, `new Dog().walk()` doesn't work, so `Dog` does not implement `AnimalMethods`. TS doesn't have a way to annotate that a class's *static* side implements an interface; see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892 for a feature request to do so. If it did, then you could maybe say `class Dog implements static AnimalMethods` or something. But it doesn't so we can't. Does this address your question fully (and I can write an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: I see where you are coming from with this. I read the discussion and the only thing that makes sense is implementation of newer syntax, which given how things usually work - would take years to be part of a stable release. The problem in my example is something that I've personally been running into for many years and the fact that TypeScript did recognise the methods when passed in as an argument made me question if there was a way. Thankyou for the comment @jcalz! You can make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: But it does show the way in the first post of that discussion: `const Dog: AnimalMethods = class Dog { public static walk() ... }` [which works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIiA5gLhgQTASwLYEMA2AsgKZQAWIAJhDALwzD64Q0KIwDeAsAFAwwAHAK4AjfJmAxouKBJgB3AgGsAFAEpU0AE6Yw7bn34wtpIVrAwA5IvxLLAbl78Avr1c9euqMS0AzXMDE6Fh4RKQU1JxOxsS4lOD4AJ4KyqjqdAB8UlA6egA0bry8vkJgwLLgDAT4GDgEJORUECq4IQQA8iIAVqi1oQ0REBowAG4gmJRRhq11+J1dAHQ2qmqOPO68wNV99eFNKmyrQA)

Comment: That is an interesting workaround, it seems to explicitly work for ```static``` methods and not ***instance*** methods which are common for classes though. A really nice workaround nevertheless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An `implements` clause on a `class` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) tells the compiler to check that *instances* of the class are assignable to the implemented type.  You use `implements` to describe class instances, not the class constructor.

That is, something like

```
class Foo implements Bar { /* ... */ }
```

will compile without error if

```
const bar: Bar = new Foo();
```

compiles without error (modulo constructor arguments).  In your example, the following are both errors:

```
const dog: AnimalMethods = new Dog(); // error
new Dog().walk() // error
```

So an instance of the `Dog` class is *not* a valid `AnimalMethod`, so `class Dog implements AnimalMethods {}` is and should be an error.

---

There is currently no analogous clause to say that the class *constructor* implements an interface.  There's a longstanding open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892) asking for something like this.  If and when such a feature is ever implemented, it might look like:

```
// Not valid TS as of 4.6, don't write this:
class Dog implements static AnimalMethods {
    public static walk(): string {
        return 'walk';
    }
}
```

But for now it's not available to us.  All we have are workarounds.  And these workarounds are all similar to something like

```
callAnimalMethods(Dog);
```

That is, we can get the compiler to tell us whether or not the `Dog` value itself is assignable to `AnimalMethods`.  You can't get this check right on the `class Dog {}` line, but you can get it close.  For example:

```
type DogCheck = Implements<AnimalMethods, typeof Dog>; // okay
class Dog {
    public static walk(): string {
        return 'walk';
    }
}
```

where `Implements` is just a dummy helper type like

```
type Implements<T, U extends T> = void;
```

And you can see that it gives errors if the static side fails to satisfy the to-be-implemented interface:

```
type CatCheck = Implements<AnimalMethods, typeof Cat>; // error!
// -------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
//   Property 'walk' is missing in type 'typeof Cat'
class Cat {
    public static talk(): string {
        return 'meow';
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9jZBvAUDpBS8ANiFFEgCJoDmSAlmDMRJMAC4UCCwjIxAWQjsAFmgAmFXIRlIYAVwBGxevCRR2IdqqQB3fgGsAFAEoAXOvYAnesDrTZjq8PlXgSAOT7iBjwG58RyQAX0CCULCiNGANJHFaCx4+QWExSSQAXiRgCF0qWlM-JAB6YqQIKys0K0icvOoaUwA6b2MTErKKqprI23YKgDMEZCSwfiFRCSlImWcQeOBiAE89QwtTTIA+Sxs7ABpIiJkB+WB4bWiifmJR8dSpoxBeMeIAeUUAK0Tnu8nJcyQADc0PRxEgHI4nsl3h8WoZCoc8DJ4Ndbik-lAjA0TAEcBFQJBYMMkAAxeTsVwQAQgJaKbCRYoAKkiJDIFAaDCYLDYnEsWh0aImaWmQTkShUag0-LUrVMFg0u3sMyCzgpbk8rX8yvCiJkjOKeLwBOgcEQSAA6tUDCAqqcwbhIuwlpgkABJLmsCAcKAAHgAKnskABVcoAD36wHSfu2WWBoNxMidLoaAGERBB4AZMm6PTzfYL7pJA0mIGgBvkaJsiqUkGhrUsWaRyBXwdqxcodFLtDL4QCFbYlaLZi51V5DFrRaEZEdCCWkCmtGmM1msu7mJ7vT6Cxji87S+WF+wqx1ypVqgBCBllAC0t7v94fj6fz+v2wAfh-P1+r4QAApVTArCdDVxwYCgwHocgBwYdw5w8Esy3nLQPEbNkkPYVtRQUDtJU0bskE0Hw5R2aCISHVVXHcDxIDQXQJyCKdCAiXoOEGYlt2FTCVQgeZomWVYfHWdoMm2ft9kRSITjOC53BRYgbh+dFhUeRSYW+ZIhSmAE43tNsoReGE4SInEJORVFFM0yQsVoEzgiAA)